# Ember Set/Save Doesn't Update Computed Properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on a simple budgeting app with 2 models: Category and Entries. Categories have many entries.

Ember 2.2

**Problem:** Categories have computed properties `total` and `difference` that watch associated entries. These computed properties update when entries are added and removed, but not when entry attributes change.

Here is the Category model:

```
# app/models/category.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name:          DS.attr('string'),
  budgetAmount:  DS.attr('number'),
  budgetSheet:   DS.belongsTo('budget-sheet'),
  entries:       DS.hasMany('entry'),

  total: Ember.computed('entries.@each.amount', {
    get() {
      let entries = this.get('entries');

      return entries.reduce(function(previousValue, entry){
        return previousValue + entry.get('amount');
      }, 0);
    }
  }),

  difference: Ember.computed('budgetAmount', 'total', {
    get() {
      return this.get('budgetAmount') - this.get('total');
    }
  })
});
```

Here is the route:

```
# app/routes/budget-sheet.js
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model(params) {
    return this.store.find('budget-sheet', params.budgetSheetId);
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('budgetSheet', model);
    controller.set('categories', model.get('categories'));
  }
});
```

Here is the controller with the actions to add/remove/update entries:

```
# app/controllers/budget-sheet.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  entries: Ember.computed('categories.@each.entries', {
    get() {
      let result = [];

      this.get('categories').map(function(category) {
        category.get('entries').forEach(function(entry) {
          return result.push(entry);
        });
      });

      return result;
    }
  }),

  actions: {
    ...

    updateEntry(id, attribute, value) {
      let entry = this.store.peekRecord('entry', id);
      entry.set(attribute, value);
      entry.save();
    },

    deleteEntry(id) {
      let entry = this.store.peekRecord('entry', id);
      entry.destroyRecord();
    }
  }
});
```

The template iterates through `categories` and displays the computed properties. The template also has an `entry-form` component that is responsible for sending data to the functions in the controller (`addEntry`, `updateEntry`).

When an entry is added or removed, the template is updated. When an entry's category is changed, the template is updated. When an entry's amount is updated, the template does not update.

Comment: I don't know, what ember-version you are on, but have you tried: `total: Ember.computed('entries.[].amount', ` ?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I'm on Ember 2.2. I did try updating the computed properties to the `entries.[].amount`, but that didn't fix the issue of the properties not updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did run into [this open Bug that @jeffreyj linked.](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12475)

But you could just work around that by replacing

```
total: Ember.computed('entries.@each.amount', {
```

with

```
total: Ember.computed('entries.content.@each.amount', {
```

This is because `entries` will return a `PromiseArray` and there is `@each` currently broken. But unter the `content` you have the actual value, so this will work.

Comment: Thanks for the verification on what I had found and for providing a better workaround that doesn't tie up the relationship to `async: false`. +1

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is a bug around computed properties in Ember 2.1.1 and 2.2.0 as described by this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12475

A comment in the Github issue recommended manually setting `{async: false}` on the hasMany relationship, which worked for my problem. This change corrected all issues that I was having with computed properties not updating:

```
# app/models/category.js
  - entries: DS.hasMany('entry'),
  + entries: DS.hasMany('entry', {async: false}),
```

Comment: This *may* works for your case, but but using the `content` workaround is definitely the better solution, because often your relationship needs to be async.

Answer (score -1):

In Ember 2.2 @each is no longer present, although you don´t get any error using it the result of object.@each is always an empty array

if you only want to get I would personally use a property function

EDIT: **This is wrong** for properties model.@each.property is still correct link to deprecation guide in answers

Comment: I believe that `@each` as a leaf has been deprecated, but not `@each.prop`. Can you provide a reference for your "no longer present" assertion?

Comment: @torazaburo @christian-stengel From what I can see in the release notes, `.@each` as a leaf has been deprecated in favor of `.[]`, but `@each.prop` hasn't.

Comment: @torazaburo you are correct, I wasn´t aware of that [link](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/)